# Robot FrameWork : repeater fails to locate element :Element locator with prefix 'repeater' is not supported

Tags: selenium-webdriver, angularjs-ng-repeat, robotframework

I'm using `Extend2seleniumLibrary` and I'm unable to find element using `ng-repeat`.
When doing so I get the error:

> Element locator with prefix 'repeater' is not supported.

The code which is used is

`Get Text  |  repeater=action in vm.actionList@row[0]`   (made sure the tabs are right)

1. How to use repeater in robot framework?
2. Any guide to learn the use of these locators in robot framework ?

Comment: what do you expect `repeater=` to do? It's not a recognized locator, which is exactly what the error is telling you. Also, what is `Extend2seleniumLlibrary`? A google search doesn't pull up anything with that name.Is it a custom  library?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the documentation, this is something that can be generated from the Python code itself. The Online [ExtendeSelenium2Library keyword documentation](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-extendedselenium2library/doc/ExtendedSelenium2Library.html).

From the documentation I took the following table. As you can see, the locator `repeater` does not feature in here and that is why you get the error message.

AngularJS Locators Support:

```
AngularJS Strategy            Example                           Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
model   Click Element         | model=model_name                Matches by AngularJS model name
binding Click Element         | binding=binding_name            Matches by AngularJS binding name
partial binding Click Element | partial binding=binding_name    Matches by partial AngularJS binding name
button  Click Element         | button=My Button                Matches button elements by their button text
partial button  Click Element | partial button=y But            Matches button elements by their partial button text
options Get WebElements       | options=options_descriptor      Matches by AngularJS options descriptor
```

The `repeater` locator is supported by another library: [AngularJSLibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs). Do you have them mixed up?

Comment: Can i include  AngularJSLibrary with Robot Framework? If so, how to add it in my test robot file ?

Comment: [AngualarJSLibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs) _is_ a Robot Framework Library. On the GitHub project page the installation and usage are clearly explained.

Comment: When I use as follows in Settings | Library | Selenium2Library and Library | AngularJSLibrary ,  I get the error that add Angular library to red.xml. But still i get the error. But when I use it in a py file it works. Can I ask you if i could use  Library | EntendedSelenium2Library and Library | AngularJSLibrary in my setting

Comment: I don't understand ".. when I use it in a py file it works ..". From the AngularJSLibrary source code I determined that it is fixed to Selenium2Library. So it replaces the ExtendedSelenium2Library.